# Translation of "Trying is the first step towards failure"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

A somewhat famous quote by Homer Simpson:

> Trying is the first step towards failure

How would this be translated into Latin?

Both a direct translation and/or a shortened version capturing the essence could work.

Comment: While that is actually an authentic quote from Homer, on *this* website many people's first association is bound to be the Greek writer of the same name, so you may want to clarify you are talking about *Homer Simpson*.

Comment: Yes, that's the joke. Should not affect the answer to the question. Feel free to edit if unappreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Conari est incipere errare" is an easy rendering of this quote directly from English to Lain. "To try is to begin to err."

You could also do "Conari est initium erroris" meaning "To try is the beginning of an error."